# xlwings :: UDF - Automation Error

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I am trying to build a `xlwings UDF function` which calculates results for specified scenarios. The code works usings Jupyter Notebook (i.e. without UDF). However, when I implement as UDF (using Windows) the function just returns "Automatisierungsfehler" (`automation error`) in the cell where the function is entered. So no issues when importing the function but when it is actually calculating...

Input for the function:

- x: cells with values to be replaced with scenario values
- y: cells with scenario values
- z: cell with result

Here is my code:

```
import xlwings as xw

@xw.func
@xw.arg('x', xw.Range)
@xw.arg('y',xw.Range)
@xw.arg('z',xw.Range)
@xw.ret(expand = "vertical")
def calc_scenario(x,y, z):
    address = x.address
    formula = x.formula

    res = []
    for scenario in y.value:
        x.value = scenario
        res.append(z.value)

    x.formula = formula

    return res
```

When using this code in excel I can import the function with no problem. When using it the formula (=calc_scenario(...)) just returns "Automatisierungsfehler".

> The same code works from Jupyter Notebook:

```
import xlwings as xw

sht = xw.Book("TestStuff.xlsm").sheets[0]

def calc_scenario(x,y, z):
    address = x.address
    formula = x.formula

    res = []
    for scenario in y.value:
        x.value = scenario
        res.append(z.value)

    x.formula = formula

    return res

x = sht.range("C43:H43")
y = sht.range("C47:H49")
z = sht.range("C45")
calc_scenario(x,y,z)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!